In rust's rocket, why can I copy state from request guards, but not when retrieving it via Rocket::state?
This route, which simply sets a key-value in Redis, compiles and runs successfully:
#[post("/thing", data = "<msg>")]                                                                                                                                                                                     
async fn post_thing(mut redis_conn: Connection<Redis>, msg: Json<Thing<'_>>) -> Value {                                                                                                                               
    redis::cmd("SET")                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        .arg(&[msg.name, msg.description])                                                                                                                                                                            
        .query_async::<_, ()>(&mut *redis_conn)                                                                                                                                                                       
        .await                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        .unwrap();                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    json!({ "name": msg.name, "description": msg.description })                                                                                                                                                       
}

I am attempting to implement FromRequest to expose my User type to certain routes. This involves retrieving from Redis the user id associated to a given session id. Inside the FromRequest implementation, state is accessed slightly differently. Rather mut redis_conn: Connection<Redis> being a function parameter, it is retrieved via request.rocket().state::<Connection<Redis>>():
let redis_conn = match request.rocket().state::<Connection<Redis>>() {                                                                                                                                        
            Some(x) => x,                                                                                                                                                                                             
            None => {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                return rocket::outcome::Outcome::Error((                                                                                                                                                              
                    http::Status::InternalServerError,                                                                                                                                                                
                    UserGuardError::FailedToGetDatabaseConnection,                                                                                                                                                    
                ))                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        };

The problem is this --- request.rocket().state::<Connection<Redis>>() gives me an immutable reference to the state (a &Connection<Redis>) rather than a copy of it. This prevents me from calling redis::cmd("GET").arg(...).query_async::<_, String>(&mut *redis_conn):
`redis_conn` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

I tried to copy Rocket State via * but it does not implement Copy. I expected this to work because my post_thing route demonstrates copying such state.

There is a misunderstanding here: Connection<Redis> (assuming this is from the rocket-db-pools crate) does not come from the state just as Json<Thing> does not come from the state. You would use the State type for that. Connection<Redis> is a request guard which is manifested on each request. Internally it accesses the database pool from the state and wraps a connection from it. Your solution below, using .guard is correct.

I solved my problem by retrieving the Connection<Redis> object via request guards, rather than via request.rocket().state::<T>(). Example:
    async fn from_request(request: &'r Request<'_>) -> request::Outcome<Self, ()> {
        // Using `State` as a request guard. Use `inner()` to get an `'r`.
        let outcome = request.guard::<&State<MyConfig>>().await
            .map(|my_config| Item(&my_config.user_val));

        // Or alternatively, using `Rocket::state()`:
        let outcome = request.rocket().state::<MyConfig>()
            .map(|my_config| Item(&my_config.user_val))
            .or_forward(Status::InternalServerError);

        outcome
    }

I found this in the docs here.
